# Sed print with evaluated date command on back reference

Tags: bash, unix, date, sed

I have a file (as one often does) with dates in *nix time as seconds from the Epoch, followed by a message and a final "thread" field I am wanting to select. All separated with a '|' as exported from a sqlite DB...

e.g

```
1306003700|SENT|21
1277237887|SENT|119
1274345263|SENT|115
1261168663|RECV|21
1306832459|SENT|80
1306835346|RECV|80
```

Basically, I can use sed easily enough to select and print lines that match the "thread" field and print the respective times with messages, thus:

```
> cat file | sed -n "s/^\([0-9]*\)\|\(.*\)\|80$/\1 : \2/p"
1306832459 : SENT
1306835346 : RECV
```

But what I really want to do is also pass the time field through the unix date command, so:

```
> cat file | sed -n "s/^\([0-9]*\)\|\(.*\)\|80$/`date -r \1` : \2/p"
```

But this doesn't seem to work - even though it seems to accept it. It just prints out the same (start of Epoch) date:

```
Thu  1 Jan 1970 01:00:01 BST : SENT
Thu  1 Jan 1970 01:00:01 BST : RECV
```

How/can I evaluate/interpolate the back reference \1 to the date command?

Maybe sed isn't the way to match these lines (and format the output in one go)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl is handy here:

```
perl -MPOSIX -F'\|' -lane '
    next unless $F[2] == "80";
    print(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %T", localtime $F[0]), " : ", $F[1])
' input.file
```

Comment: Works exactly as it says. Not so compact - but good old perl.

Answer (score 4):

awk is perfect for this.

```
awk -F"|" '$3 == '80' { print system("date -r " $1), ":", $2 }' myfile.txt
```

Should work.(Can't guarantee that the system call is right though, didn't test it)

Comment: I like this for its "one liner" aspect - however, the system call seems to print directly on a newline and (weirdly) the return code is then printed (a zero) before the colon as $1. e.g 
Tue 31 May 2011 16:18:08 BST **\n** 0 : SENT **\n**

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure of how to change this behavior, unfortunately. Perl might be a better choice

Comment: Yep - no worries. Shame as I always like the conciseness of awk and sed for these things, but it seems this is deficiency in how they can call out to further commands. Will use Perl for now.

Answer (score 3):

This pure bash

```
wanted=80
(IFS=\|; while read sec message thread
do
        [[ $thread == $wanted ]] && echo $(date -r $sec) : $message
done) < datafile.txt
```

print

```
Tue May 31 11:00:59 CEST 2011 : SENT
Tue May 31 11:49:06 CEST 2011 : RECV
```

You can quote variables in " " for the better safety...

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
 sed -n 's/^\([0-9]*\)|\(.*\)|80$/echo "$(date -d @\1) : \2"/p' file | sh
```

or if you have GNU sed:

```
 sed -n 's/^\([0-9]*\)|\(.*\)|80$/echo "$(date -d @\1) : \2"/ep' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **awk**:

```
$(awk -F'|' '/80$/{printf("echo $(date -d @%s) : %s;",$1,$2);}' /path/to/file)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `date` command will be executed before the `sed` command.

It may be easiest to break out perl or python for this job, or you can use some kind of bash loop otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Rafe's answer above:

```
awk -F"|" '$3 == '80' { system("date -d @" $1 " | tr -d \"\n\""); print " :", $2 }' myfile.txt
```

For my version of date, it seems that `-d` is the argument, instead of `-r`, and that it requires a leading `@`. The other change here is that the [system](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html#index-system_0028_0029-function) call executes (so date actually does the printing, newline and all - hence the `tr`) and returns the exit code. We don't really care to print the exit code (0), so we move the `system` call outside of any `awk` `print`s.